# java 9 module reads package X from A and B

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, java-9, java-module

I am trying to use spring boot with java 9 and gradle.
I am unable to run my simple code, I get the below mentioned error :-

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'Java9Gradle_main'
Information:javac 9-ea was used to compile java sources
Information:6/9/2017 10:40 PM - Compilation completed with 65 errors and 0 warnings in 15s 200ms
Error:java: module  reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module  reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter.web reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter.web reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.boot.autoconfigure reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.boot.autoconfigure reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter.logging reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter.logging reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.core reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.core reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module snakeyaml reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module snakeyaml reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter.tomcat reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter.tomcat reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module hibernate.validator reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module hibernate.validator reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module jackson.databind reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module jackson.databind reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.web reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.web reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.webmvc reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.webmvc reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.context reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.context reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module logback.classic reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module logback.classic reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module jcl.over.slf4j reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module jcl.over.slf4j reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module jul.to.slf4j reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module jul.to.slf4j reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module log4j.over.slf4j reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module log4j.over.slf4j reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module commons.logging reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module commons.logging reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module tomcat.embed.core reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module tomcat.embed.core reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module tomcat.embed.el reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module tomcat.embed.el reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module tomcat.embed.websocket reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module tomcat.embed.websocket reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module validation.api reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module validation.api reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module jboss.logging reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module jboss.logging reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module classmate reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module classmate reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module jackson.annotations reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module jackson.annotations reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module jackson.core reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module jackson.core reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.aop reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.aop reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.beans reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.beans reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.expression reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.expression reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module logback.core reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module logback.core reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module slf4j.api reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module slf4j.api reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.boot.starter reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.boot reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
Error:java: module spring.boot reads package org.apache.commons.logging.impl from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
D:\project\Java9Gradle\src\main\java\module-info.java
Error:(1, 1) java: module Java9Gradle.main reads package org.apache.commons.logging from both jcl.over.slf4j and commons.logging
```

My dependencies file and the module-info.java file are very straight forward.

```
module Java9Gradle.main {
    requires spring.boot;
}


group 'Java9Gradle'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.9

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Can someone please help??

Thanks,

Amar

Answer (score 4):

Excluding the transitive dependency made it work and adjusting the module-info.java too!!!

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.3.RELEASE") {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.3.RELEASE"){
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
```

Comment: What adjustments were required in the module-info.java file?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Jigsaw specs](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/reqs/)

> Non-interference — The Java compiler, virtual machine, and run-time
>   system must ensure that modules that contain packages of the same name
>   do not interfere with each other. If two distinct modules contain
>   packages of the same name then, from the perspective of each module,
>   all of the types and members in that package are defined only by that
>   module. Code in that package in one module must not be able to access
>   package-private types or members in that package in the other module.

This is referred to as *split packages* in the answer by @Andy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42358212/1746118). The solution thereby is to unsplit these packages and make sure that the packages that are included from your modules `jcl.over.slf4j` and `commons.logging` are accessed via only one module.

---

You can analyze both dependencies `spring-boot-starter:1.5.3.RELEASE` and `spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.3.RELEASE` to make sure either of the two modules is included in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Such problem occurs for multiple libraries like Apache Mina (sshd-core) where there is split between sshd-core and sshd-common. Similar for Springfox Swagger 2, where you can get similar split package problem: "*Module XXX reads package springfox.documentation service from both springfox.core and springfox.spi.*"

After analysisg multiple ways how to overcome it I have found one solution which works for all cases.

The idea is to repackage the offending libraries into single jar and install them into your company (or local repository). If you have company-wide nexus you can install it, otherwise prior to running the whole build you can manually install such library to local maven repository.

While these seems like overkiller and something which can not be easily done, in fact it is quite easy.

You need to create new maven module in your main project (or create separate maven project if you are not running multimodule project). Then you add the dependencies which introduces package split to your pom.xml and configure maven assembly plugin to repackage them.

For spring-fox this will be

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-core</artifactId>
        <version>${io.springfox.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${io.springfox.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${io.springfox.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-schema</artifactId>
        <version>${io.springfox.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${io.springfox.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-spi</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Please notice two things. First `<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>` as a configuration parameter for assembly plugin. Second exclusion of all the transient dependencies, so that they do not get included into the final package.

After pom.xml is prepared you can go to your new module directory and run `clean install` or `clean package` to create a package with all the dependencies compiled into single jar. The jar will be located under your target folder. This way you will create file which you name, for example, like `springfox-all-3.0.0.jar` (containing all the springfox code in single module).

Now you can install this package into either your local repo or better deploy it to your  nexus, for example with following command

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dversion=3.0.0-SNAPSHOT -Durl=http://nexus.youc.company.net/nexus/content/repositories/yourRepoId -Dfile=springfox-all-3.0.0.jar -DgroupId=patched.io.springfox -DrepositoryId=yourRepoId -DartifactId=springfox-all
```

Now use this dependency instead of set of single dependencies in your project both in your pom.xml file and in your module-info.java

```
module com.acme.your.module {

//  requires springfox.spring.web;
//  requires springfox.swagger2;
//  requires springfox.core;
//  requires springfox.spi;
  requires springfox.all;
}
```