# How to fix the issue with Java 9 Modularity after adding dependency on mongock?

Tags: mongodb, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system, mongock

We are developing Spring Boot application that is using MongoDB as storage.
And we want to add to our project the DB migration tool: [mongock](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock).

in `pom.xml` I added a new dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongock-spring</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And IntelliJ Idea advised me to add the following lines to `module-info.java`:

```
requires mongock.spring;
requires mongock.core;
```

After that I am not able anymore to build the project, I am getting the following error:

```
Module 'com.acme.project-name' reads package 'com.github.cloudyrock.mongock' from both 'mongock.spring' and 'mongock.core'
```

I do not know a lot about Java 9 Modularity, that why I am stuck with resolving this issue, please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's worth solving this issue one could upgrade to the latest release of the artifact.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongock-spring</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.alpha</version>
</dependency>
```

You can understand what the issue means over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463552/java-9-module-reads-package-x-from-a-and-b) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358084/package-conflicts-with-automatic-modules-in-java-9/42358212#42358212) Q&A.

If you were to analyze the issue, you could straightforward notice that with the version `3.3.2`, there are two artifacts that are brought in as a dependency under external libraries - `mongock-spring` and `mongock-core`. Further, if you look at the JARs, you would see their package structure is the same( i.e. both have classes within `com.github.cloudyrock.mongock`) and that is the reason for conflict that you see while they both are introduced in the modulepath.

***Edit***: Extended discussions to be moved over to [#mongock/issues/212](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock/issues/212).

Comment: does it mean, that there is an issue with mongock itself? and there is no way to use 3.3.2 version?

Comment: @user471011 It means that you can't use `mongock-spring:3.3.2` on the modulepath at least. So without the `module-info.java`, you can still work with the combination of Java-9+ and `3.3.2`. (your dependencies should be on the classpath)