# Is it possible to mix --class-path and --module-path in javac (JDK 9)?

Tags: java, classpath, java-9, java-platform-module-system, module-path

When I compile a module that depends on other modules I've compiled previously I have to specify the `--module-path <directory>` option. This makes modules I depend on visible.

But at the same time I would also like to make some non-modular Jar files visible. However if don't make them automatic modules and just specify the `--class-path some.jar` right next to `--module-path <directory>`, then **javac** seems to ignore the claspath and throws "package yyy not found" and other  "not found" errors.

I can understand that using `--class-path` and `--module-path` at the same (compile) time is illegal, but **javac** does not warn me against it in any way.

Comment: It is possible to mix the two, can you share a minimum example that we can verify ?

Comment: *I can understand that using --class-path and --module-path at the same (compile) time is illegal,* why is that so?

Comment: Mixing is absolutely legal. However, modular jars cannot reference non-modular jars on the classpath. Automatic modules (non-modular jars on the modulepath) act as a bridge: modular jars _can_ reference them, and automatic modules can read the classpath.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use class path and module path in parallel, but there are a few details to consider.

## Dependency Module Path ~> Class Path

Explicit modules (JARs with a module descriptor on the module path) can not read the unnamed module (JARs on the class path) - that was done on purpose to prevent modular JARs from depending on "the chaos of the class path".

Since a module must require all of its dependencies and those can only be fulfilled by other named modules (i.e. not JARs on the class path) all dependencies of a modular JAR must be placed on the module path. Yes, even non-modular JARs, which will then get turned into [automatic modules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#automatic-modules).

The interesting thing is that automatic modules *can* read the unnamed module, so *their* dependencies can go on the class path.

## Dependency Class Path ~> Module Path

If you compile non-modular code or launch an application from a non-modular JAR, the module system is still in play and because non-modular code does not express any dependencies, it will not resolve modules from the module path.

So if non-modular code depends on artifacts on the module path, you need to add them manually with [the `--add-modules` option](https://blog.codefx.org/java/five-command-line-options-to-hack-the-java-9-module-system/#Extending-The-Module-Graph-With--add-modules). Not necessarily all of them, just those that you directly depend on (the module system will pull in transitive dependencies) - or you can use `ALL-MODULE-PATH` (check the linked post, it explains this in more detail).

Comment: Nicolai - your answer is correct but I think could be expanded to point out that the `--add-modules` option may be needed to ensure that the modules needed by class path code are resolved. The original question asks why javac fails and I assume this is because he/she is compiling code on the class path with references to classes in modules on the module path and just needs `--add-modules` to ensure that the modules are resolved.

Comment: I think OP is trying to compile modular code with a non-modular dependency - either way, I added the other direction as well, just to make sure.

Comment: @AlanBateman I tried to mix -classpath and --module-path during compilation and it fails even though I use --add-modules.
`javac -cp lib\* --module-path modules --add-modules simpleModule -d out @classes.txt`
where: `lib`-is folder with my jars, which I want to use in unnamed module; `modules` - contains a folder (folder name = simpleModule) with module-info.java inside; `@classes.txt`- list of classes for compilation (including modular classes from modules folder); `simpleModule`- module name from 'modules' folder. After I run this command I get `package does not exist` for jar in `lib`dir

Comment: @ZimboRodger Try quotes around `lib/*`, e.g. `'lib/*'` or `"lib/*"`. If that does not help, please open a new question.

Comment: @Nicolai Did not help. Raised a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537980/mix-class-path-and-module-path-in-javac-jdk-9

Comment: You likely found this by now, and I might be misinterpreting the remarks, but automatic modules *must* be jars. A simple folder doesn't work.

Comment: how to do it in gradle project?

Answer (score 11):

I believe using the `--classpath` and `--module-path` options at the same time is ***not illegal***. It's possible to use both at the same time as even when you don't explicitly specify a classpath it *defaults* to the current directory.

Details from the `javac -help` message and [javac tools docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9__BHCGAJDC) -

```
--module-path <path>, -p <path>
```

Specify where to find application modules

```
--class-path <path>, -classpath <path>, -cp <path>
```

Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors

> *If `--class-path`, `-classpath`, or `-cp` **aren’t specified**, then the user
>   class path is the **current directory**.*

---

***Edit***: Thanks to @MouseEvent, I'd probably missed out the  part in the question

> However if don't make them automatic modules and just specify the
>   --class-path some.jar right next to --module-path , then javac seems to ignore the claspath and throws "package yyy not found"
>   and other "not found" errors.

If you don't make them automatic, it's treated as an [Module System's unnamed module](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module) and -

> A named module cannot, in fact, even declare a dependence upon the
>   unnamed module. This restriction is intentional, since allowing named
>   modules to depend upon the arbitrary content of the class path would
>   make reliable configuration impossible.

Moreover, the **unnamed** module exports all of its packages hence the code in an **automatic** modules will be able to access any public type loaded from the classpath.

But an automatic module that makes use of types from the classpath *must not expose those types to the explicit modules that depend upon it*, since explicit modules cannot declare dependencies upon the unnamed module.

> If code in the explicit module `com.foo.app` refers to a public type
>   in `com.foo.bar`, e.g., and the *signature of that type refers to a
>   type in one of the JAR files still on the class path*, then the code
>   in `com.foo.app` will not be able to access that type since
>   `com.foo.app` cannot depend upon the unnamed module.

This can be remedied by treating `com.foo.app` as an automatic module temporarily so that its code can access types from the class path, until such time as the relevant JAR file on the class path can be treated as an automatic module or converted into an explicit module.

Comment: @MouseEvent Well that's true. I believe I missed that part of the question though previously and just answered the title. Edited to include that as well. Thanks :)