# Unnamed module interaction with named module by ServiceLoader::load

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, module-info

I have a project like this:

```
\---main
    \---src
        \---com.foo
            \---UnnamedStart.java
\---api
    \---src
        \---com.foo.api
            \---ApiInterface.java
        \---module-info.java
\---impl
    \---src
        \---com.foo.impl
            \---ApiInterfaceImpl.java
        \---module-info.java
```

Implementatio of `UnnamedStart.java` is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServiceLoader<ApiInterface> services = ServiceLoader.load(ApiInterface.class);
    ...
}
```

Note that *main* is unnamed module.

`api/src/module-info.java` is:

```
module com.foo.api {
     exports com.foo.api;
}
```

and `impl/src/module-info.java` is:

**update 1.1** - code below updated see comments, added `requires`

**update 1.2** - code below updated, `provides A with B` changed to `provides B with A` mistake during creating question, originally was ok

```
module com.foo.impl {
     requires com.foo.api; //added (update 1.1)
     provides com.foo.impl.ApiInterface
         with com.foo.api.ApiInterfaceImpl; //vice versa (update 1.2)
}
```

When I run my code in `UnnamedStart.java` I end up with no element in `services`.

I also tried to create a static method in `com.foo.api.ApiInterface`:

```
static List<ApiInterface> getInstances() {
    ServiceLoader<ApiInterface> services = ServiceLoader.load(ApiInterface.class);
    List<ApiInterface> list = new ArrayList<>();
    services.iterator().forEachRemaining(list::add);
    return list;
}
```

and add in `api/src/module-info.java` line `uses com.foo.api.ApiInterface;` but it gave the same result (nothing).

The only way I made it work is by migrating *main* from unnamed to named module.

**1. How does *java 9* work when unnamed module trying to interact with named module?**

**2. Does it possible to make it work and keeping the *main* like unnamed module?**

**update 1.3** - [added related project](https://github.com/akhmelov/service-loader-problem)

Comment: module com.foo.impl seems to be missing `requires com.foo.api` so I doubt it will compile. In any case, you'll need to run with `--add-moduels com.foo.impl` to ensure that the com.foo.impl module is resolved - you need this because no module declares requires it and no other module `uses com.foo.api`.

Comment: @Andrew Additionally, when you migrated to a *named module*, did you not put a `requires com.foo.api` in the main module descriptor?

Comment: @nullpointer - the initial module is on the class path so it doesn't have a module-info. Mixing the module path and the class path is okay, I suspect he's just missing `--add-modules com.foo.impl`.

Comment: @AlanBateman Agreed over that for the case when the OP is using an unnamed module. The question also mentioned about migrating to a named module(module path). That's when I was asking about the `requires` directive being used in the module descriptor.

Comment: `requires com.foo.api` - originally I have this, miss add it here
Yes, you are right, I forgot to put `--add-modules com.foo.impl`, also I used wrong command to run my project, now it works fine with `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-9.0.4/bin/java -classpath /path/main/target/classes -p /path/api/target/classes:/path/impl/target/classes --add-modules com.foo.impl com.foo.UnnamedStart`. Thanks and could you answer please :)

Comment: @nullpointer "did you not put a requires com.foo.api in the main module descriptor?" - I put it

Comment: @AndrewChmielowski I meant the same(maybe sarcastically), that you needed the requires within the impl module(as in your edit) to compile the code in the unnamed scenario as well. Also, the module resolution still needed the impl to be resolved during the startup. To check which you could also [make use of the `--show-module-resolution`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339598) flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*ServiceLoader::load* works as usual, but the are other things.

**[Short answer]**

**1.** *Unnamed module* reads the same like *named module* to *named module*, but *named module* can not access types in the *unnamed module*.

**2.** You are trying to launch an application from a non-modular JAR so you have to explicitly resolve required modules by [`--add-modules com.foo.impl`](https://blog.codefx.org/java/five-command-line-options-to-hack-the-java-9-module-system/#Extending-The-Module-Graph-With--add-modules).

Note that your required modules have to be on *module graph* (e.g. add by `--module-path`).

**[More details]**

**1.** There are 4 different types of modules: *built-in platform module, named module, automatic module,* *unnamed module* and each of them are named apart from *unnamed module*

[As they wrote](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module) the *unnamed module* treats all the other modules the same like *named module*:

> All other modules have names, of course, so we will henceforth refer to those as named modules.
>
> The unnamed module reads every other module. [...]
>
> The unnamed module exports all of its packages. [...] It does not, however, mean that code in a named module can access types in the unnamed module. A named module cannot, in fact, even declare a dependence upon the unnamed module. 
>   [...]
>
> If a package is defined in both a named module and the unnamed module then the package in the unnamed module is ignored.

Even an *automatic module* indeed is also [named](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#automatic-modules):

> An automatic module is a named module that is defined implicitly, since it does not have a module declaration.

**2.** [Second part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288170/is-it-possible-to-mix-class-path-and-module-path-in-javac-jdk-9/46289257#46289257)

> If you compile non-modular code or launch an application from a non-modular JAR, the module system is still in play and because non-modular code does not express any dependencies, it will not resolve modules from the module path.
>
> So if non-modular code depends on artifacts on the module path, you need to add them manually with [the `--add-modules` option](https://blog.codefx.org/java/five-command-line-options-to-hack-the-java-9-module-system/#Extending-The-Module-Graph-With--add-modules). Not necessarily all of them, just those that you directly depend on (the module system will pull in transitive dependencies) - or you can use `ALL-MODULE-PATH` (check the linked post, it explains this in more detail).

This @nullpointer comment will be useful

> Also, the module resolution still needed the impl to be resolved during the startup. To check which you could also [make use of the `--show-module-resolution`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339598/list-the-modules-resolved-during-the-application-startup) flag.

Comment: Nice answer :) Was thinking of writing one myself, but this one is sufficiently detailed.