# Apache POI module not found compilation error

Tags: java, apache-poi, java-module

I'm using Apache POI 4.1.0 library to read/write Microsoft Word document. I'm using JDK 11 (java modules in play here) with module definition. My project build fails to compile with "module not found: poi.ooxml". How do I get this to work?

Apache POI FAQ https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N102B0 says Apache POI version 4.1.0 supports Java 11 modules, but something is off and my project fails to compile.

Java class using Apache POI

```java
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '4.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.0'
}
```

module-info.java

```java
module x.server {
    exports com.sample.x.server;
    requires poi.ooxml;
}
```

I've tried using

```java
module x.server {
    exports com.sample.x.server;
    requires org.apache.poi.ooxml;
}
```

I expect it to build successfully, but it fails to compile with :

Task :server:compileJava FAILED
./server/src/main/java/module-info.java:3: error: module not found: poi.ooxml
    requires poi.ooxml;
                ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: Please update the question with the complete error message. You can find quite a few questions on SO, which reads module not found as a problem as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50353001/java-9-automatic-modules-not-found Maybe you're running into a similar issue?

Comment: Updated the compete error.