# Gradle with Java 10 (Spring able to scan module classes even when package not exported)

Tags: spring, gradle, java-9, java-platform-module-system

So I am playing around with Spring and Java 10 along with Gradle.

In my application, I created 2 modules

- UI
- Application

The application module's gradle file looks like this

```
dependencies {
    compile project (':ui')
}
```

And module-info file looks like this

```
module application {
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.boot;
}
```

In my UI module, the build.gradle looks like this

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:${vaadinVersion}"
    }
}
```

And module-info looks like this

```
module ui {
    requires vaadin.server;
    requires vaadin.spring;
}
```

So my UI code lives inside ui module. As you can see, I am not exporting any package outside from the ui module and application's module-info also doesn't require ui.

In the main class I added

```
@ComponentScan("com.factory_manager")
```

And magically it's able to scan the UI module and the vaadin UI classes and I am able to access them via their respective endpoints.

From my understanding, the application module should not be able to read ui module's classes as I am not exporting any package outside.

Does anyone has any idea on how spring is magically able to scan the ui module and find the ui classes?

And yes, I am unable to access UI module's classes inside my application module but spring somehow is able to..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very gradle specific, yet a probable reason for this could be your dependency code -

```
dependencies {
    compile project (':ui')
}
```

Due to which the `ui` module classes are present on the classpath instead of the module path and are under [the unnamed module](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module).

To correlate further, the unnamed module *exports all of its packages* and hence you're able to access those classes without exporting them.

Top of my mind, one way you can confirm this is, by trying out something like -

```
<yourClassFromUIModule>.class.getModule().isNamed(); //should return false
```

Comment: I tried to remove dependency on ui project. Then I added the relevant export in ui module-info. Problem is that if I want to add requires ui, in my application module's module-info then I need gradle dependency on ui in my application's build.gradle file :S..

Comment: @Sneh If you need the dependency, you certainly need it in the gradle. The difference is in the presence of that dependency on the classpath versus on the modulepath.

Comment: @Sneh See [Building Java 9 Modules (in Gradle)](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/).

Comment: Hmm I think I am getting it now. Spring is able to scan it because it is present in the classpath of application module.

Comment: Thanks @Slaw, will check it out.

Comment: @nullpointer as far as I understand, the piece of code won't help me becsause to be able to access the class, I will need to export it and then require it, which will then end up putting it in a "named" module.

Comment: Ahh wait, it doesn't make any sense.. It returns me false even after having a requires on ui module and exporting the package. I will investigate more. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I did more investigation and somehow suddenly without any code change `<yourClassFromUIModule>.class.getModule().isNamed(); ` is returning true. And spring is unable to load the class without me adding a requires ui...

Comment: @Sneh both of us know, it cannot be just something sudden. Would suggest looking at the [modules resolved while you start your application.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339598/list-the-modules-resolved-during-the-application-startup)

Comment: Yep, I completely agree with you @nullpointer. I think it might have to do with gradle versions. I will look into it further. Thanks.