# How to add an external dependency to openjfx

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, java-module, openjfx

I'm playing around trying to add lwjgl as a dependency to the `graphics` module.

I already modified the graphics [`module-info`](https://github.com/elect86/openjdk-jfx/blob/develop/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/module-info.java#L40-L41):

```
module javafx.graphics {
    requires java.desktop;
    requires java.xml;
    requires jdk.unsupported;
    requires org.lwjgl;
    requires org.lwjgl.opengl;
```

Added a custom repo and declared the required libs into `dependencies`, always within [`graphics`](https://github.com/elect86/openjdk-jfx/blob/develop/build.gradle#L1910-L1936)

Then I fixed step-by-step all the dependencies for `graphics` [here](https://github.com/elect86/openjdk-jfx/blob/develop/build.gradle#L2006-L2012), [here](https://github.com/elect86/openjdk-jfx/blob/develop/build.gradle#L2029) and [here](https://github.com/elect86/openjdk-jfx/blob/develop/build.gradle#L2194)

However now I'm struggling to fix the next error:

```
> Task :media:compileJava FAILED
Task ':media:compileJava' is not up-to-date because:
Task has failed previously.
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':media:compileJava'.
Compiling with Java command line compiler 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\javac.exe'.
Starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\javac.exe''. Working directory: C:\Users\elect\openjdk-jfx\modules\javafx.media Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk- 11.0.1\bin\javac.exe @C:\Users\elect\openjdk-jfx\modules\javafx.media\build\tmp\compileJava\java-compiler-args.txt
Successfully started process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\javac.exe''
C:\Users\elect\openjdk-jfx\modules\javafx.graphics\src\main\java\module-info.java:40: error: module not found: org.lwjgl requires org.lwjgl;
^
C:\Users\elect\openjdk-jfx\modules\javafx.graphics\src\main\java\module-info.java:41: error: module not found: org.lwjgl.opengl requires org.lwjgl.opengl;
^
```

I guess I shall add lwjgl into the module path of  project `media`, but I run out of options..

I tried to modify the `media` `module-info`, the `compileJava` task, nothing.. I couldnt make it work

How may I solve it?

Comment: What are your dependencies for `org.lwjgl.opengl` and `org.lwjgl`? Are you sure they are there on modulepath? Why is your module named `javafx.graphics`? If its at application startup, [can you check the modules resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339598/list-the-modules-resolved-during-the-application-startup)?

Comment: I got the answer to why the name (you're working on a forked repo). Another thing, did you look at [Building OpenJFX prerequisites](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX)

Comment: Did you try a clean?

Comment: @nullpointer, I guess you mean [these](https://github.com/elect86/openjdk-jfx/blob/develop/build.gradle#L1920-L1935)? No, I'm not sure. If I look at the `graphics` `java-compiler-args.txt` it looks [fine](https://gist.github.com/elect86/7f4894d34b93c749428cf0ef351061b5). And [this](https://gist.github.com/elect86/98f8e337418c8347eb14f49dfd32a892) is the one of `media`.

Comment: @EM-Creations, `gradle clean`? Just tried, nothing changed..

Comment: If you only changed `graphics`, why would `media` complain?

Comment: @user1803551, that's a good question.. my best guess is because `media` depends on `graphics`, which in turn depends on `lwjgl`..

Comment: Try `requires transitive` in `module-info.java`.

Comment: for `media` or `graphics`?