# IntelliJ JavaFX 12 Artifact: no main manifest attribute, but it is there?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, artifact

Little confused here. Looked around and haven't found anything. Lots of people seem to be having similar problems but I haven't seen a solution yet.

I cloned the IntelliJ gradle non-moduler hellofx sample application from [here](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/IDE/IntelliJ/Non-Modular/Gradle).

Builds and runs okay, good.

I then tried to build an artifact. I did `Add -> JAR -> from modules with dependencies...`

Resulting in:

[image]

Building the artifact and trying to run it gives me the following error:

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -jar E:\hellofx\out\artifacts\hellofx_main_jar\hellofx_main.jar
no main manifest attribute, in E:\hellofx\out\artifacts\hellofx_main_jar\hellofx_main.jar`

But the Main-Class attribute *is* in the manifest file that was generated when building the artifact:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicated of [How to open JavaFX .jar file with JDK 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53533486/how-to-open-javafx-jar-file-with-jdk-11/53536555#53536555)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with help from Jose's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53533486/how-to-open-javafx-jar-file-with-jdk-11/53536555#53536555).

I had to add the native libs from the bin folder from javaFX.

I had to take extra steps because building with gradle wasn't putting the fxml and class files together in the build. So I had to add this to my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
  //...
  id 'idea'
}

sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = "build/classes/java/main"

idea {
    module.outputDir file("out/production/classes")
}
```

In addition I had to move the META-INF folder into the resource folder so when building it was placed in the correct location.