# Why is my Java 9 Module service not having its implementations registered?

Tags: java, service, java-9, java-module

I am learning Java 9 Module by reading the book "[Modular Programming in Java 9](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/modular-programming-java-9)". In chapter 7, Introducing services, at page 201, I followed the steps by the book to create a simple project using service. I will post the code below or you can visit the project on [github](https://github.com/peckwood/p205_Implementing_sorting_services).

1. service

module name: packt.sortutil

class full name: packt.util.SortUtil

```
public interface SortUtil {
    <T extends Comparable> List<T> sortList(List<T> list);
}
```

2. providers
class full name: packt.util.impl.bubblesort.BubbleSortUtilImpl:
code:

```
package packt.util.impl.bubblesort;
public class BubbleSortUtilImpl implements SortUtil 
...
```

module-info.java

```
module packt.sort.bubblesort {
    requires packt.sortutil;
    provides packt.util.SortUtil with packt.util.impl.bubblesort.BubbleSortUtilImpl;
}
```

There is also `packt.util.impl.javasort.JavaSortUtilImpl` with the only difference of a different implementation.

3. consumer

module-info.java:

```
module packt.addressbook {
    requires packt.sortutil;
    uses packt.util.SortUtil; 
}
```

code:

```
Iterable<SortUtil> sortUtils = ServiceLoader.load(SortUtil.class);
for (SortUtil sortUtil : sortUtils){
    System.out.println("Found an instance of SortUtil");
    sortUtil.sortList(contacts);
}
```

When I run consumer, it **should be**:
[image]

Note the highlighted area, where 2 implementations are found. Also, the names are sorted by the last name.

**But** for my program, **it is:**

```
2月 03, 2019 12:12:55 上午 packt.addressbook.Main main

INFO: Address book viewer application: Started

2月 03, 2019 12:12:56 上午 packt.addressbook.Main main

INFO: Address book viewer application: Completed

[Edsger Dijkstra, Raid Black]
```

Notice there are *no "Found an instance of SortUtil"* and the names are not sorted. So it appears as if there are no implementations registered with the service.

Where did it go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You also need to ensure that both your module with implementation(e.g. `packt.sort.bubblesort `) are resolved on the modulepath while you're executing your consumer code. Check [this link on how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339598/list-the-modules-resolved-during-the-application-startup) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**What I did**

@nullpointer's suggestion is helpful. I used `java --module-path out --module packt.addressbook/packt.addressbook.Main` to debug the see the module path, and found out:

```
root packt.addressbook file:///D:/ebooks/Modular%20Programming%20in%20Java%209/
ce-code/p205_Implementing_sorting_services/out/production/packt.addressbook/
packt.addressbook requires packt.sortutil file:///D:/ebooks/Modular%20Programmi
n%20Java%209/practice-code/p205_Implementing_sorting_services/out/production/pa
rtutil/
packt.addressbook requires java.logging jrt:/java.logging
packt.addressbook requires packt.contact file:///D:/ebooks/Modular%20Programmin
%20Java%209/practice-code/p205_Implementing_sorting_services/out/production/pac
tact/
packt.contact requires java.xml jrt:/java.xml
...
```

Module `packt.sort.bubblesort` and `packt.sort.javasort` were not present in the module path. Then I checked the output folder and saw that these 2 provider modules' were not compiled. I figured out that the reason is these 2 modules werenot readable by any other modules and therefore omitted during compilation.

When I used the command `D:\programs\java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\javac -d out --module-source-path .\*\src -m packt.addressbook`, it looks for modules that module`packt.addressbook` dependent on, including service module `packt.sortutil`, but since `packt.sortutil` and other modules do not depend on the 2 service modules,`packt.sort.bubblesort` and `packt.sort.javasort`, they are omitted. Actually, they depend on the service module instead.

---

**Solutions**

So I changed to command to manually compile these 2 modules: `javac -d out --module-source-path .\*\src -m packt.addressbook,packt.sort.bubblesort,packt.sort.javasort`. And it is fixed now.

There is another [project](https://github.com/verhas/module-test) that uses maven to the fix this issue. The consumer module(`packt.addressbook` in my example)'s POM depends on the provider module(`packt.sort.bubblesort` and `packt.sort.javasort` in my example):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax0</groupId>
    <artifactId>Provider</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I am not sure if this is the best practice, though.

---

**Follow up**

If someone knows how to manually add modules for compilation or automatically discover provider modules 'providing` a service module for compilation inside a IDE like IntelliJ IDEA, please let me know.