# JPMS ServiceLoader does not work for me as expected

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system, serviceloader

*JPMS ServiceLoader* does not work for me as expected.

I am trying to provide a **desktop program as an executable jar** with a default service, that can be overloaded by the individual user. A user provides their own service class and give their name as an argument on the commandline.

The **service**:

```
package eu.ngong.myService;

public interface MyService {
    public String name();
    public void doSomething();
}
```

The **program** together with the **default service** (the first lines in the *if* and the *for* are inserted for logging):

```
package eu.ngong.myService;

import java.util.ServiceLoader;

public class ServiceUser implements MyService {
    private static MyService myService = new ServiceUser();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("trying to load " + args[0] + " envirionment.");
            ServiceLoader<MyService> myServices = ServiceLoader.load(MyService.class);
            for (MyService ms : myServices) {
                System.out.println(ms.name());
                if (ms.name().equalsIgnoreCase(args[0])) {
                    myService = ms;
                }
            }
        }
        myService.doSomething();
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("The default service is acting.");
    }

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "Default";
    }
}
```

Both collected in **myService.jar** with the main class of ServiceUser hosting the module-info.java

```
module MyService {
    exports eu.ngong.myService;
    provides eu.ngong.myService.MyService with eu.ngong.myService.ServiceUser;
}
```

An **individual jar** at a user may be

```
package eu.ngong.user1;
import eu.ngong.myService.MyService;
public class User1 implements MyService {

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "User1";
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("User1 is acting.");
    }

}
```

with the module-info.java

```
module User1 {
    requires MyService;
    provides eu.ngong.myService.MyService with eu.ngong.user1.User1;
}
```

However, **running** the program with

```
java -p ..\user1\user1.jar;myService.jar -jar myService.jar User1
```

leads only to the **unexpected** output

```
trying to load User1 environment.
The default service is acting.
```

While I **expected** with logging

```
trying to load User1 environment.
Default
User1
User1 is acting.
```

What did I miss?

Comment: And if you remove the "-jar myService.jar" and replace it by the main class directly: `eu.ngong.myService.ServiceUser` ? And, did you add a `META-INF/eu.ngong.myService.MyService` referencing the implementation?

Comment: @NoDataFound The `-jar` versus `-m` should be mostly similar. The `META-INF/services` is a good suggestion, but as long as modules are recognized as explicit, that might not be required either in my opinion.

Comment: @NoDataFound: Switching to *-m* was one part of the solution.
citing Oracle: *When you use -jar, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to declare

   ```
   uses eu.ngong.myService.MyService;
   ```

in the module where you want to execute the service loading code.

2. Try ensuring your packaging added `META-INF/services` for the correct resolution of modules via jar files if processed as automatic.

---

Since this wouldn't fit in the comments, hence sharing the findings of a similar example here. I could notice upon execution via IntelliJ that the code just worked with the `uses` declaration and the classpath of `user-service` module.

Further I tried to use a similar command line:

```
java --show-module-resolution -p base-service/target/classes:user-service/target/classes --add-modules base.service,user.service -m base.service/base.service.ServiceUser user1
root base.service file://.../base-service/target/classes/
root user.service file://.../user-service/target/classes/
user.service requires base.service file://.../base-service/target/classes/
base.service binds user.service file://.../user-service/target/classes/
...
trying to load user1 environment.
Services found : 2
User1
Default
User1 is acting.
```

and added the [`--show-module-resolution`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339598/list-the-modules-resolved-during-the-application-startup) to seek why providing the jar's on the module path didn't work. The output was as follows and had a difference where the service module was [not able to bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693148/what-does-a-module-a-binds-module-b-mean-in-the-resolution) the user module.

```
java --show-module-resolution -p base-service/target/base-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:user-service/target/user-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --add-modules base.service,user.service -m base.service/base.service.ServiceUser user1
root base.service file://...base-service/target/base-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar automatic
root user.service file://...user-service/target/user-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
user.service requires base.service file://...base-service/target/base-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar automatic
.....
trying to load user1 environment.
Services found : 1
User1
User1 is acting.
```

This might be the cause for unexpected output in the way you are executing as well. The slight difference being the `Default` implementation is not resolved in the latter for me.

Comment: The *module-info.java in the module where I want to execute the service loading code* has to get a *uses interface* statement. --

There is nothing to be put below META-INF or in MANIFEST.MF with respect to *ServiceLoader*. *module-info.class* hosts all the information required to specify a *jar* file as a Java module, even a module using a service or providing one. Automatic modules may be different.

Comment: @ngong true, the behavior with automatic module seems to be different. That's why I have asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693148/what-does-a-module-a-binds-module-b-mean-during-the-resolution?noredirect=1&lq=1) to follow up. Related to the `uses` the [`ServiceLoader` API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) reads it clearly I believe.

Comment: @ngong I’m confused by your comment. You are right that you don’t need to mess around with `META-INF` nor `MANIFEST.MF`, but how does that relate to the beginning of your comment? The `uses` directive is precisely for modular software, going into the `module-info`.

Comment: @Holger I'm also confused by your comment. module-info.class goes into the jar file. It is not related to META-INF or MANIFEST.MF. What I am happy about is, that I can stay on Java level, maintaining module-info.java, produce a simple jar file and do not have to worry about getting information from the Java source to any text file (MANIFEST.MF) in the jar file. For me this is an improvement of ServerLoader technology that comes with JPMS.

Comment: @ngong and I never said anything else. The integration of the service loader into the language was a great improvement. But this doesn’t change the fact that your module declaration (the version posted in your question) lacks a `uses` declaration.

Comment: @Holger: correct, we are on the same track - just confusions.