# What does a module.a binds module.b mean during the resolution?

Tags: java, java-module, java-platform-module-system

While performing a proof of concept for a problem -  [JPMS ServiceLoader does not work for me as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68691750/jpms-serviceloader-does-not-work-for-me-as-expected).

I reached a state to understand the difference in how the two modules were resolved when providing a jar versus target classes to the module path. The console had a one-line difference that of:

```
base.service binds user.service file://.../user-service/target/classes/
```

What does this effectively mean? Couldn't really find such reference of this term in the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7.3) or the [conceptual draft](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/).

Additionally, when could such behavior differ during automatic module resolution? (refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68693222/1746118))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This most likely refers to the *bind* operation of [`resolveAndBind`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/Configuration.html#resolveAndBind(java.lang.module.ModuleFinder,java.util.List,java.lang.module.ModuleFinder,java.util.Collection)) processing `uses`—`provides` relationships.

> This method works exactly as specified by [`resolve`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/Configuration.html#resolve(java.lang.module.ModuleFinder,java.util.List,java.lang.module.ModuleFinder,java.util.Collection)) except that the graph of resolved modules is augmented with modules induced by the service-use dependence relation.
>
> More specifically, the root modules are resolved as if by calling `resolve`. The resolved modules, and all modules in the parent configurations, with [`service dependences`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.html#uses()) are then examined. All modules found by the given module finders that [`provide`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.html#provides()) an implementation of one or more of the service types are added to the module graph and then resolved as if by calling the `resolve` method. Adding modules to the module graph may introduce new service-use dependences and so the process works iteratively until no more modules are added.

So, binding takes place after resolving, but still before any code of the involved modules has been invoked. Namely, it doesn’t matter whether the `ServiceLoader` is actually used within the module(s) or not. But when it is used, it will utilize the already available information. So a lot of potential problems have been precluded at this point already. This is also the reason why we could build optimized module images pre-linking such services.

This, however, doesn’t work with automatic modules, as they don’t have `uses` directives. Without that information, service lookups can only be done when an actual use of `ServiceLoader` happens, just like with classes loaded through the old classpath.

---

Note that the issue in the linked Q&A is a bit different. According to the OP’s information, a module declaration has been used when compiling. But then, the OP ran the application using the `-jar` option which puts the specified jar file on the *classpath* and loads it from there, creating an *unnamed* module, rather than an automatic module. This ignores the compiled `module-info` and in absence of old-fashioned `META-INF/services/…` resources, no service implementation was found at all. The OP’s code was designed to fall back to the default service implementation if none had been found, which is indistinguishable from the scenario of finding the default service through the `ServiceLoader`.

The crucial differences of your answer are the start method `-m base.service/base.service.ServiceUser`, which will locate the `base.service` through the module path and launch its `base.service.ServiceUser`, as well as `--add-modules …user.service`, to ensure that the module providing the service will be added to the runtime environment. The latter is needed since there is no direct dependency from the launched module `base.service` to the `user.service`, so it wouldn’t be loaded automatically.

So in your answer’s setup, both modules are loaded as such. When they have a `module-info`, its `provides` directive will be processed to find the service implementation, otherwise, it’s an automatic module and must have a `META-INF/services/…` file. As said above, there is no equivalent to the `uses` directive for automatic modules, so you will never see a “binds” log entry for them. But they may still use the service lookup.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for reminding me about the `unnamed` module resolution via the code and command in OP's question. Follow-up question, in the [last command of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68693222/1746118) .. `java --show-module-resolution -p base-service/target/base-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:user-service/target/user-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --add-modules base.service,user.service -m base.service/base.service.ServiceUser user1`, without the `META-INF/services/…`, the user service is loaded and not the default one, why would that be the case?

Comment: @Naman I can only guess about the details of your setup. According to the output, only `base.service` was an automatic module, the `user.service` was not. So for the latter, the `module-info` has been used and if it contains a `provides` declaration, that’s the reason why its service implementation has been loaded.

Comment: Not to guess further, the reproducible example is [here on github](https://github.com/namannigam/module-services)in case you would want to review. The `module-info` is part of both the modules(jars) and I was using Java-17 to build and execute.

Comment: Well, the `base-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` does not have a `module-info`, which is what makes it an automatic module. So it’s precisely what I supposed, one is an automatic module (without a `META-INF/services/…` resource), the other is not (having a `module-info` with `provides`). So one module’s service implementation is available in this setup.

Comment: Yeah, spot on. The expectation difference and that I noticed it now, with `maven-shade-plugin`(at least with the present configuration) the `module-info.class` doesn't get packaged in the jar.

Comment: @Holger: Thank you for the explanation why -jar ignores the -p for ServiceLoader. To support learning - as I did - and analysis I uploaded my results (so far) to [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/ngong1/jpms_serviceloader_example)