# Muting Java 9 split package errors on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, module, compiler-errors, java-9

I have a JDK 9 project. When running `mvn install`, everything works fine. When using IntelliJ 2017.2.6 with JDK 9.0.4 I come up
with dozens of compilation errors due to split packages. For example, in my POM I set a dependency on `org.apache.solr:solr-core:7.2.1`. One of the errors displayed by IntelliJ is:

```
Error:java: module solr.core reads package org.apache.lucene.search from both lucene.misc and lucene.sandbox
```

The rationale for the compilation error issued by IntelliJ is:

1. `solr-core` has Maven dependencies on artifacts `lucene-misc` and `lucene-sandbox`
2. Both `lucene-misc.jar` and `lucene-sandbox.jar` define classes in package `org.apache.lucene.search`
3. IntelliJ considers that `lucene-misc.jar` and `lucene-sandbox.jar` are JDK 9 modules (if fact, they are not modules, they have no `module-info.java` file). As two JDK 9 modules cannot participate to the same package, IntelliJ issues a compilation error.

By contrast, the Maven compiler pluging issues no error, because it considers `lucene-misc.jar` and `lucene-sandbox.jar` as belonging to
the class path, not to the module path.

I obviously don't want to re-package the Lucene stuff.

So my problem boils down to the following: how can I mute IntelliJ errors `Error:java: module Mod1 reads package P from both Mod2 and Mod3`?

Comment: Delete your module-info.java

Comment: Your direct dependencies have to go onto the module path, but transitive dependencies can go on either path. Maven places them on the class path (where split packages don't matter), whereas IntelliJ places them on the module path (leading to the problems you observe). I know of no way to tell IntelliJ where to place transitive dependencies. Resorting to a non-modular project might be your only choice.

Comment: Thanks @ZhekaKozlov and Nicolai. Hopefully the JetBrains folks will make this behaviour configurable in a next version of IntelliJ.

Comment: I have seen a case now where IntelliJ appears to be incorrectly flagging something as a split package when there is none. The case is very simple, so I think this could be a bug. I'm waiting for a response, but details are here:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010504179-IntelliJ-Flags-Split-Package-but-not-Maven

Answer (score 4):

**[Short]**

It's impossible if you want to run your application from a module code. You have to migrate your code which depend on collision JARs to *non-modul*e code and add your collitions jar on the class path. (as suggested in comments)

**[Long]**

Behind the scene the *Intellij* try to run the *JVM*, so the *Intellij* can run your application only if the *JVM* can do that.

When you run an application from module jar, that means that you run your application from  named module. The module must require all of its dependencies which should be name modules. Note that even *automatic module*s which are created from your non-module *JARs* are indeed named. 
*Java 9* does not allow *split-packages* for the reason of the reliable configuration, only *unnamed module*s are excepted from this rule.

The only way to make it works it move your collision jars to *unnamed module*, but [named module cannot depend on unnamed module](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module)

> A named module cannot, in fact, even declare a dependence upon the *unnamed module*. This restriction is intentional, since allowing named modules to depend upon the arbitrary content of the class path would make reliable configuration impossible.

so if you don't want repackage collision jars you have to move your modules which require collision *jars* to non-module jar.

Your maven plugin done with it, because as @Nicolai said:

> Maven places them on the class path (where split packages don't matter), whereas IntelliJ places them on the module path (leading to the problems you observe).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288170/is-it-possible-to-mix-class-path-and-module-path-in-javac-jdk-9/46289257#46289257) about running the application from *non-module* code.

Comment: Thanks very much @Andrew.