# Can't import java.awt.* and javax.swing.* in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, import, package, java-9

The title said it all. I can't import neither java.awt.* nor java.swing.* in Intellij Idea. This is my project structure.

[image: project structure]

```
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Your module `requires java.desktop` in the directives for that. Have you ensured it? Or could you better explain what is your current project structure and definition?

Comment: Could your better explain what is your project structure? if you define explicity your project as module (`module-info` present) you will have to add `requires java.desktop` as @nullpointer suggested, but if not than you shoudn't this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288170/is-it-possible-to-mix-class-path-and-module-path-in-javac-jdk-9/46289257#46289257

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how i done it. It seems that i need to include a module-info.java file

[image: module-info.java]

and inside that put the follwoings.

```
module project.name {
    requires java.datatransfer;
    requires java.desktop;
}
```

I can't come up with a better answer right now. but this solved the initial problem.