# javac returns "error: module not found: ini4j"

Tags: java, javac

I've got a small program (presently six `*.java` files, plus the `ini4j-0.5.4.jar` library). It works fine from Eclipse, but I need to compile and run it on a system with no graphics capability, so I've built a `javac` command for it, to be run from the project directory:

```
javac -d bin -classpath libs/ini4j-0.5.4.jar src/main/*.java
```

When it runs, it produces two lines:

```
error: module not found: ini4j
1 error
```

I've been away from Java programming for some years, and I'm just catching up with the changes for modules and such. It seems that that's the source of the trouble: the `ini4j` file was written before modules were a thing. I've seen hints that there's a way to make a modular Java program work with non-modular components, and obviously it works when I run it from the Eclipse GUI, but the way to coax the `javac` compiler to accept it eludes me.

I'm using openjdk (and javac) 11.0.3 under Ubuntu 19.04, if that helps.

**Bottom line: how can I get this non-modular JAR file to compile into a new (modular, simple) Java program with the `javac` command-line compiler?**

---

**SOLUTION:** With the help of the comments and answer, I found a way to fix the problem, by altering the `javac` command line to this:

```
javac -g -d bin --module-path libs/ini4j-0.5.4.jar src/main/*.java
```

Now it doesn't give me any problems when compiling. :-) Still trying to figure out how to actually *run* it from the command line, but that's a different subject.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but it seems related: [Mix --class-path and --module-path in javac (JDK 9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537980/mix-class-path-and-module-path-in-javac-jdk-9)

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java`?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html

Comment: Also have a look [here](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is given here in the comments section - [Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: - Maven with JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395749/error-automatic-module-cannot-be-used-with-jlink-maven-with-javafx)

> The unfortunate thing about `jlink` is it can only create images when
>   everything is an explicit module (i.e. has a `module-info` file). At
>   least one of your dependencies (`ini4j`) is not an explicit module; see
>   [What is an automatic module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741907/what-is-an-automatic-module)? for more information. You have at least a
>   few options:
>
> (1) Modify/fork the dependency to be an explicit module,
>
> (2) fallback to the classpath and package your application in a "fat" jar
>
> (3) try `jpackage` (early-access, I doubt javafx-maven-plugin
>   provides support yet)

Personally, I'd recommend to go with option #2. Use any appropriate maven/gradle plugin to package your app as an executable JAR. It'll be easier to deal with the app and its dependencies now and later.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who needs it , i have ported ini4j to be used in as module

Can be found here : https://github.com/codebbgr/cbbini4j

Also fixing some bugs as well