# java.lang.module.ResolutionException when adding tess4j dependency to pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, java-platform-module-system, tess4j

When I add tess4j to my dependencies, it throws following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules slf4j.simple and logback.classic export package org.slf4j.impl to module xmlgraphics.commons
```

I understand, that there is some dependency that uses the same "org.slf4j.impl" as tess4j.
My dependencies are following:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.20</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.sap</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/technology.tabula/tabula -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>technology.tabula</groupId>
        <artifactId>tabula</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.onepassion</groupId>
        <artifactId>SDScomXML</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>29.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

How do I know which package is the "faulty" one? And how do I fix it to not export the package named in the errortext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56828520/java-lang-module-resolutionexception-when-adding-google-cloud-datastore-dependen) I solved the problem. Seems like both modules logback-classic and slf4j are from tess4j. I just added exlusions for them like this:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

And now it seems to start normaly without any errors. Maybe logging isn't working anymore but that's okay for me.