# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.ResolutionException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, postgis

Currently I am working for some homework, with postgis.jdbc in combination with postgis.geometry and postgresql.
The problem is now that Intellij always throws the following error when running the programm.

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules postgis.geometry and
> postgis.jdbc export package org.postgis to module org.postgresql.jdbc
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I tried different ways to import, but nothing seems to work.

According to the following entry I should use classpath instead of modulepath but I can't find a setting to import a jar file using class path instead of module path.

I tried to import using Runtime instead of compile option but the packages are no longer recognized by Intellij, so this is not a working option for me.

Thanks for help.

[image]

Comment: It is several dependencies conflict. See comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62237354/external-modules-a-and-b-export-package-some-package-to-module-c-in-java-9