# I want to understand modularity in java. When compiling my app I have a ResolutionException

Tags: java, javafx, module

I have 2 separate javafx modular projects created with Gradle and IntelliJ Idea. The first one is an app I will name it A. The second is a library, I will name it B.

I want to use library B in my app A, and when I run my app, the Gradle task main fail with this message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer.
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: 
  Module org.kasburn.moduleB contains package javafx.concurrent,
  module javafx.graphics exports package javafx.concurrent to org.kasburn.moduleB.
```

Content of `module-info.java` of project A:

```
module org.kasburn.moduleA {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires org.kasburn.moduleB;
}
```

Content of `module-info.java` of project B:

```
module org.kasburn.moduleB {
    requires javafx.graphics;
    exports org.kasburn.moduleB;
}
```

I don't know what to do to resolve it. Project B is built as an artifact jar and the two projects really needs javafx.controls and javafx.graphics.

I can't remove javafx.controls nor javafx.graphics , and I have test with transitive keyword but no visible effect.

Comment: How do you create moduleB?  Provide the `build.gradle` for it.  Check the content of the built jar (jav tvf <jarfilename).  Ensure it has no JavaFX classes in it.  Probably you are doing the Gradle equivalent of maven shade when you build moduleB, placing code from the JavaFX library inside the module jar.  The module jar should not be shaded, it should only contain the class and resources for moduleB, not the modules that moduleB depends on (those should be on the module path separately).

Comment: Here is how you [correctly create and use a JPMS modular JavaFX library built using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76317530/1155209).  I don't use Gradle much, so won't advise on that.  The link I provided is for modular UI component usable in scenebuilder.  You can ignore the scenebuilder part of the linked answer if you don't use that tool.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Modules A and B export package some.package to module C in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46277188/modules-a-and-b-export-package-some-package-to-module-c-in-java-9)