# Java module system and AspectJ

Tags: java

I have 2 libraries, which I have migrated to Java 10 and used module system.

First thing which makes me worry is that I had a lot of errors like:
`Error:java: the unnamed module reads package org.aspectj.internal.lang.reflect from both aspectjrt and org.aspectj.weaver`. To fix that, I have added `requires org.aspectj.weaver;` to module info. Actually I had to put there lot of other things which I don't use, but e.g. Spring uses. Only then I was able to compile it.

So in the end, my module-info for the first library looks like this:

```
module my.lib1 {
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.context.support;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires org.aspectj.weaver;
    requires slf4j.api;
    requires metrics.core;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    requires java.validation;
    requires org.hibernate.validator;
    requires javax.el;

    exports my.lib1;
}
```

For the second library I also had to add a lot of libs that are used by dependencies, not me:

```
module my.lib2 {
    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
    requires java.sql;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.tx;
    requires spring.orm;
    requires spring.data.jpa;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires HikariCP;
    requires metrics.core;
    requires slf4j.api;
    requires spring.core;

    exports my.lib2;
}
```

Both libs are compiling now. I put them in my local mvn repo and started third project which depends on this two.

```
module my.project {
    requires my.lib1;
    requires my.lib2;
}
```

And now I got the same error... `Error:java: the unnamed module reads package org.aspectj.internal.lang.reflect from both aspectjrt and org.aspectj.weaver`, but this time, adding `requires org.aspectj.weaver;` doesn't help. **I have noticed when I put only one of the libs in the module (not both together, but one lib1 or lib2) it works.**

Is it normal that I have to put different libs in my module-info which are used not by my but by other dependencies? (e.g. shouldn't it be Spring's responsibility to require aspectj?).

And the most important thing: how do I fix the problem with my project which depends on my two libs?

Answer (score 2):

> I have noticed when I put only one of the libs in the module (not both together, but one lib1 or lib2) it works.

Using the module system, a package may *only be offered by a single module in your current module graph*. This is one of the main reasons for the introduction of the module system: avoidance of ambiguous dependencies (as they occur on the classic class path; called [split packages](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/modules/split-packages.html)). And that's why it works with only one of your modules.

In your case, both modules `aspectjrt` and `org.aspectj.weaver` are offering the same package `org.aspectj.internal.lang.reflect` and that's where the error message comes from (`the unnamed module reads package org.aspectj.internal.lang.reflect from both aspectjrt and org.aspectj.weaver`).

> how do I fix the problem with my project which depends on my two libs?

like [Andy Guibert wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42358212/9818506) to this topic, you could:

1. unsplit the package
2. bundle them in a single package
3. hope that third party modules become named modules in the future.

AspectJ has been ported to the module system. Check the newest [version](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-190.html), if you don't use it (`requires org.aspectj.runtime`, `requires org.aspectj.weaver`)?

Additionally, [here](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-module-system-tutorial/) you can find some more information about the module system.